# Driver not found exception for org.postgresql.Driver during spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to learn a Scala-Spark JDBC program on IntelliJ IDEA. In order to do that, I have created a Scala SBT Project and the project structure looks like:

Before writing the JDBC connection parameters in the class, I am trying to load a properties file which contains all my connection properties and trying to display if they are loading properly as below:

testconnection.properties:

```
devUserName=username
devPassword=password
gpDriverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
gpDevUrl=jdbc:url
```

Code:

```
package com.yearpartition.obj

import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object PartitionRetrieval {

  var conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark-JDBC")
  val conFile = "/home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/testconnection.properties"
  val properties = new Properties()
  properties.load(new FileInputStream(conFile))
  val connectionUrl = properties.getProperty("gpDevUrl")
  val devUserName=properties.getProperty("devUserName")
  val devPassword=properties.getProperty("devPassword")
  val gpDriverClass=properties.getProperty("gpDriverClass")

  println("connectionUrl: " + connectionUrl)

  Class.forName(gpDriverClass).newInstance()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().config(conf).master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
    println("connectionUrl: " + connectionUrl)
  }
}
```

Contents of build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11" % "provided",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.3"
)
```

When I do the spark-submit I get the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Spark submit command:

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --class com.yearpartition.obj.PartitionRetrieval yearpartition_2.11-0.1.jar --driver-class-path /home/hmusr/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --jars /home/hmusr/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar
```

I have the postgres jar file in the dir: /home/hmusr/jars/ and also in the sbt dependencies.
Could anyone let me know what is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: The `provided` scope must only be used for dependencies that are provided at runtime (there it means by Spark). For other dependencies, their scope should not be `provided` (and they must be embedded in your dist).

Comment: It's the provided scope that is causing problems here.

Comment: I removed the parameter "provided" and this is what I gave: "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.1" and this is the spark-sibmit: SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --class com.yearpartition.obj.PartitionRetrieval yearpartition_2.11-0.1.jar --driver-class-path /home/hmusr/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --jars /home/hmusr/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar , but I still get the same error

Comment: Any mistake in the code ?

Comment: did u rearranged commands n tried ? like : SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit  --driver-class-path /home/hmusr/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --jars /home/hmusr/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --class com.yearpartition.obj.PartitionRetrieval yearpartition_2.11-0.1.jar

Comment: @Sukumaar This worked.

Comment: @eliasah Corrected the mistake and thanks for the concept.

Comment: @cchantep Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the driver class on your classpath. Download this jar from [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.1.jar)

Use `--jars` to pass it to `spark-submit`. 
Note `--jars` will not work for `local` mode.

in an sbt project add this to your lib directory when building it.

Comment: I did both. You can see that in my spark-submit command. I passed the '--jar' parameter and I even have it on build.sbt

Comment: I re arranged as per @sukumaar's comment above. It worked.

Comment: Or build your project as a standalone jar with all such dependencies (assembly, jarjar, ...)